# Validate after_unknown attribute with conftest/OPA

Tags: opa, conftest, regula

When I run the validation, conftest returns a Failure result because it's not validating with after_unknown attribute in JSON terraform plan.
If I move manually some attribute inside that block to planned_values block, it works successfully. I don't know why conftest/OPA is not including after_unknown block

**How I'm running Regula**

I'm running this command

docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/project openpolicyagent/conftest test tfplan33.json --output table

using the policies located in regula Repo (https://github.com/fugue/regula)

**IaC Configuration**
The common tf plan, the result of:

terraform plan -out=tfplan

terraform show -json ./tfplan > tfplan33.json